# Need solution for this CB BJT circuit

Tags: bjt, circuit-analysis

How can I solve this circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVCeLD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This capacitor confuses me when I tried to do DC biasing.

Also when I draw small signal equivalent circuit( T model ) to find the equation for Rin (=re) and Rout(=R1) but not Av ( voltage gain ) and Ai (current gain ).
here is my small signal equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdZbXu.png)</sup>

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to solve - you have a constant current generator in the collector and the collector itself will act as a high compliance current source and this means the normal assumptions about simple transistor models tend to rely on knowing the current gain of the transistor (which is unknown in your circuit)

Comment: No more information is provided in the question. But we can assume beta=100.

Comment: Your circuit makes no sense. With infinite capacitance on the base, the base voltage will forever stay at whatever the initial conditions are, which you haven't stated. Of course infinite capacitance is urealistic anyway, so it's hard to say what the point is.

Comment: I think infinite capacity here is to be interpreted as an open for DC bias calculations and a short for small signal calculations.

Comment: Anklon, Olin's point is a good one even if it is pedantic.  Setting the capacitance to 1/0 F is not mathematically defined.  However, we can think of and calculate with a capacitance that is *arbitrarily large* which means that it is a an open circuit for DC analysis and *effectively* a short circuit for AC analysis.

Comment: Anklon, would you please clarify if the voltage source in the emitter circuit is a DC source, an AC (or small-signal) source, or some combination?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri ; Vs is the AC small signal source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it's helpful to first draw the DC and AC circuits.

DC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVn0Z1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The operating point is evident by inspection:

$$I_C = \frac{\beta}{1 + \beta}I_2  = \alpha I_2 $$

$$V_C = I_C(\frac{75\Omega}{\alpha} + \frac{100k\Omega}{\beta}) + V_{BE} $$

---

Update to address comment:

> I can't perfectly grasp your equation for Vcc.I think understand you
>   divide resistance with beta and alpha to make them equivalent
>   resistance looking through C.

Assuming you meant \$V_C\$ rather than \$V_{CC}\$, by KVL we have

$$V_C = V_E + V_{BE} + V_{R1}$$

We have

$$V_E = I_E R_S = \frac{I_C}{\alpha}R_S $$

and

$$V_{R1} = I_B R_1 = \frac{I_C}{\beta}R_1$$

Thus

$$V_C = I_C(\frac{R_S}{\alpha} + \frac{R_1}{\beta}) + V_{BE} $$

---

AC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhDYl5.png)</sup>

The small-signal circuit is thus

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3mWCi.png)</sup>

This is a straightforward circuit to solve.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why would you leave Vs in small-signal? Voltage sources become shorts in AC small-signal analysis.

Comment: @horta, it seems reasonable to me that the OP intends \$V_S\$ to be the signal voltage source which does *not* become an AC short in small-signal analysis.  Otherwise the circuit has no small-signal source and the small-signal solution is the trivial one.

Comment: Vs is obviously different than Vi because there's a node Vi for the input voltage. In small-signal analysis, you use test voltages and/or test currents to determine the characteristics of the circuit (Av,Ai,Rin, and Rout). All current sources become opens and all voltage sources become shorts in SS analysis.

Comment: @horta, I'm *quite* well aware of how to do small-signal analysis and I disagree with your interpretation of the schematic.  For me, it's *obvious* that \$R_S\$ is the source resistance and thus, the small signal *input voltage* is, as typically *understood*, \$v_i = v_s \frac{r_{in}}{R_S + r_{in}}\$.  Look at any voltage amplifier model and you typically see that the input voltage is *not* the source voltage but is the source voltage reduced by the voltage divider formed by the source resistance and the input resistance.  For example:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/vvjgi.png

Comment: @horta, moreover, you do *not* zero signal sources in small-signal analysis.  Your statement *"**All** current sources become opens and all voltage sources become shorts in SS analysis"* is *absurd*.

Comment: I agree that Vs is the signal source voltage, and you're right that I should have specified it to be "constant voltage/current sources". I think it's still up in the air whether the OP is after an analysis of voltage gain before or after Rs, the signal resistance.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri;As I recently learn BJT and normally analyse it using loop analysis I can't perfectly grasp your equation for Vcc.I think understand you divide resistance with beta and alpha to make them equivalent resistance looking through C. But why consider Vbe but not consider whole voltage drop Vce.if you can explain or give any link which might help me to understand , that would be greatful. thnx

Comment: @Anklon, the equation is for the collector voltage \$V_C\$, not \$V_{CC}\$.  For this circuit, the only equation we have for \$V_{CE}\$ is \$V_{CE} = V_C - V_E\$ and finding these two voltage is trivial.  Ordinarily, there is a resistor between the collector and \$V_{CC}\$ and we can easily find \$V_C = V_{CC} - I_CR_C\$.  In this case, I simply found \$V_E = I_E R_E = \frac{I_C}{\alpha}R_E\$, added \$V_{BE}\$ and the voltage across \$R_1\$.  It is customary to guess a \$V_{BE}\$ between 0.65V and 0.75V for BJT DC analysis.  The guess can be refined if necessary but typically it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

In small signal, your Vs becomes a short.

Make sure you're not confusing the T and pi models. Here's a good reference:
http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/The%20Hybrid%20Pi%20and%20T%20Models%20lecture.pdf

Lastly, determine what Vout/Vin is (Av) and Iout/Iin (Ai).

Also, I doubt your Rin and Rout are so simple. To obtain those, you'll need to apply a test voltage or test current to the input and solve for the other one. Then you'll have Vin/Iin = Rin and Vout/Iout = Rout. When dealing with voltage dependent current sources like you have, you almost always need to factor that into the problem which is why you need to solve using test voltages/currents.